# Another crash in QWebView

Tags: qt, qwebview

I have another bug in the use of QWebView (Qt5.4). My application is very simple, constituted of a main window where my WebView is the central widget. In the view, the user first logs in then a page comes up where there are 3 tabs, like this :

[tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px0QO.png)

I can retrieve the information of my object using the Webkit Bridge, but if I click on any other tab, the app crashes. Here's the output:

```
ASSERTION FAILED: !m_dirty
platform\graphics\GraphicsLayerTransform.cpp(83) : WebCore::GraphicsLayerTransform::combined
```

And the callstack:

> Qt5WebKitd.dll!WTFCrash()  Ligne 345    C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::GraphicsLayerTransform::combined()  Ligne 84    C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::computeOverlapRegions(WebCore::Region & overlapRegion, WebCore::Region & nonOverlapRegion, WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::ResolveSelfOverlapMode mode)  Ligne 293 + 0x23 octets   C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::computeOverlapRegions(WebCore::Region & overlapRegion, WebCore::Region & nonOverlapRegion, WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::ResolveSelfOverlapMode mode)  Ligne 310 C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintUsingOverlapRegions(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 333 C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintRecursive(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 460   C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintSelfAndChildren(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 191 + 0x20 octets   C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintSelfAndChildrenWithReplica(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 232  C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintRecursive(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 456   C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintSelfAndChildren(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 191 + 0x20 octets   C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintSelfAndChildrenWithReplica(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 232  C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintRecursive(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 456   C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintSelfAndChildren(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 191 + 0x20 octets   C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintSelfAndChildrenWithReplica(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 232  C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintRecursive(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 456   C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintSelfAndChildren(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 191 + 0x20 octets   C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintSelfAndChildrenWithReplica(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 232  C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintRecursive(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 456   C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintSelfAndChildren(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 191 + 0x20 octets   C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintSelfAndChildrenWithReplica(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 232  C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintRecursive(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 456   C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintSelfAndChildren(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 191 + 0x20 octets   C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintSelfAndChildrenWithReplica(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 232  C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paintRecursive(const WebCore::TextureMapperPaintOptions & options)  Ligne 456   C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayer::paint()  Ligne 93   C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!WebCore::TextureMapperLayerClientQt::renderCompositedLayers(WebCore::GraphicsContext * context, const WebCore::IntRect & clip)  Ligne 141    C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!QWebFrameAdapter::renderCompositedLayers(WebCore::GraphicsContext * context, const WebCore::IntRect & clip)  Ligne 448   C++
>       Qt5WebKitd.dll!QWebFrameAdapter::renderRelativeCoords(QPainter * painter, int layers, const QRegion & clip)  Ligne 545  C++
>       Qt5WebKitWidgetsd.dll!QWebFrame::render(QPainter * painter, QFlags layer, const QRegion & clip)  Ligne 644 + 0x1d octets   C++
>       Qt5WebKitWidgetsd.dll!QWebFrame::render(QPainter * painter, const QRegion & clip)  Ligne 655    C++
>       Qt5WebKitWidgetsd.dll!QWebView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * ev)  Ligne 835 C++
>       Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QWidget::event(QEvent * event)  Ligne 8810  C++
>       Qt5WebKitWidgetsd.dll!QWebView::event(QEvent * e)  Ligne 734    C++
>       Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject * receiver, QEvent * e)  Ligne 3720 + 0x11 octets    C++
>       Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QApplication::notify(QObject * receiver, QEvent * e)  Ligne 3685 + 0x10 octets  C++
>       Qt5Cored.dll!QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event)  Ligne 935 + 0x15 octets  C++
>       Qt5Cored.dll!QCoreApplication::sendSpontaneousEvent(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event)  Ligne 231 + 0x38 octets    C++

Does anybody have an idea of how to resolve this crash?

Here's my code if needed :

```
MyObject::MyObject(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    m_pView = new QWebView(this);
    m_pView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
    m_pView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::DeveloperExtrasEnabled, true);


    connect(m_pView->page()->mainFrame(), SIGNAL(javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()), this, SLOT(addJSObject()));  

    m_pView->load(QUrl("file:///D:/DEV/Resources/index.html"));

    setCentralWidget(m_pView);
}

void MyObject::addJSObject()
{    
    m_pView->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject(QString("MyObject"), this);
}
```

Comment: Consider upgrading to Qt 5.5.1. It fixes quite a few of WebEngine problems.

Comment: We're not considering to upgrade to Qt5.5 for now (and I know that QWebView is deprecated in this one), so that's why I am asking that.

Comment: You found some workaround?